# javascript var declaration within loop

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

```
/*Test scope problem*/
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
    //declare variables
    var no = i;
    //verify no
    alert('setting '+no);

    //timeout to recheck 
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('test '+no);
    }, 500);
}
```

It alerts "setting 1" and "setting 2" as expected, but after the timeout it outputs "test 2" twice - for some reason the variable "no" is not reset after the first loop...

I've found only an "ugly" workaround:

```
/*Test scope problem*/
var func=function(no){
    //verify no
    alert('setting '+no);

    //timeout to recheck 
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('test '+no);
    }, 500);
}
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
    func(i);
}
```

Any ideas on how to workaround this problem in a more direct way? or is this the only way?

Comment: I would, also, love to see a detailed explanation of what is happening to `no`'s scope here.

Comment: @Daniel Bingham - `no`'s scope is global unless Trouts is doing this within a function. (Loops don't set a new scope in js.)

Comment: @fig-gnuton Oh.  Well that's a simple explanation for it :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript does not have block scope, and variable declarations are hoisted. These facts together mean that your code is equivalent to:

```
var no;

/*Test scope problem*/
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
    //declare variables
    no = i;
    //verify no
    alert('setting '+no);

    //timeout to recheck 
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('test '+no);
    }, 500);
}
```

By the time your timeout function executes, the loop is long finished, with `no` retaining its final value of 2.

A way around this would be to pass the current value of `no` into a function that creates a fresh callback for each call to `setTimeout`. Creating a new function each time means each setTimeout callback is bound to a different execution context with its own set of variables.

```
var no;

/*Test scope problem*/
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
    //declare variables
    no = i;
    //verify no
    alert('setting '+no);

    //timeout to recheck 
    setTimeout( (function(num) {
            return function() {
                alert('test '+num);
            };
        })(no), 500);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, it think t fully explains it. 
I originally thought the scope always worked within the {}'s in Javascript thus the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same as your fix, but using a different syntax to achieve the scoping adjustment.

```
/*Test scope problem*/
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  //declare variables 
  var no = i;
  //verify no 
  alert('setting ' + no);

  //timeout to recheck
  (function() {
    var n = no;
    setTimeout(function() { 
      alert('test ' + n);
    }, 500);
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm liking that I can get so much mileage out of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104321/how-to-assign-event-callbacks-iterating-an-array-in-javascript-jquery/1104440#1104440).

If you need help applying that answer, let me know.

### EDIT

Sure.  Let's look at your original code.

```
//timeout to recheck 
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('test '+no);
}, 500);
```

See that anonymous function? The one you pass into `setTimeout()`? It isn't called until the timer says so - which at 500ms is *well after* the loop has exited.

What you're hoping for is for `no` to be evaluated "in place" but its not - it's evaluated at the time the function is called.  By that point, `no` is 2.

In order to get around this, we need a function that executes during the iteration of the loop, which itself will return a function that `setTimeout()` can use in the way we expect it to.

```
setTimeout(function( value )
{
  // 'value' is closed by the function below
  return function()
  {
    alert('test ' + value );
  }
}( no ) // Here's the magic
, 500 );
```

Since we create anonymous function and immediately call it, a new scope has been created in which we can close off variables.  And that scope closes around `value`, not `no`.  Since `value` receives a new (ahem) value for each loop, each of these [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) has it's own value - the one we want it to.

So when setTimeout() fires, it's executing the function returned from our closure function.

I hope that explains it.

Comment: Yeah, not seeing how this relates to this question.  Can you explain a closure to a C/Java developer only just learning Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have lexical scoping(the for-loop does not create a new scope), and your solution is the standard workaround. Another way to write this might be:

```
[1, 2].forEach(function(no){
    //verify no
    alert('setting '+no);

    //timeout to recheck 
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('test '+no);
    }, 500);
})
```

forEach() was introduce in ECMAScript 5 and is present in modern browsers but not IE. You can use [my library](http://github.com/airportyh/ecma5array) to emulate it though.