# Declare var before assigning multiple values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, which format of `var` declarations is better:

```
function test1() {
  switch(type) {
    case 1:
        var test = "Hello One"
      break;
    case 2:
        var test = "Hello Two"
      break;
  }
}
```

Or:

```
function test2() {
  var test;

  switch(type) {
    case 1:
        test = "Hello One"
      break;
    case 2:
        test = "Hello Two"
      break;
  }
}
```

In **test2()**, there is 1 extra line of code to declare `test` as a `var` before assigning a value, but this saves having to declare `var test` twice. Is either way better than the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript var declaration within loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731123/javascript-var-declaration-within-loop) __because the answer explains what's happening here.__ (I'm sure there are dozens of other questions about hoisting.)

Comment: Well, actually I was asking more about the syntax of it, more than what was going on with the scoping. It's nice to learn about the term "javascript hoisting" though!

Comment: I get that, but the explanation of what's happening explains why one syntax is preferred. You sort of can't ask one without the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

javascript does not have block scope, so declaring variables in a switch block does not work like you would expect.

furthermore, due to [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), all variable declarations in a function block are hoisted to the top by the interpreter and your code would look like this:

```
function test1() {
  var test;
  var test;

  switch(type) {
    case 1:
        test = "Hello One"
      break;
    case 2:
        test = "Hello Two"
      break;
  }
}
```

After performing the hoist, it is easy to see why the first block is incorrect.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "incorrect" in your final sentence? Both examples are valid and behave identically. (I'm not disagreeing with anything you're saying in this answer, but I think it would be helpful to use a more precise term than "incorrect" -- perhaps "less clear"?)

Comment: @apsillers "incorrect" meaning a bad practice that static analysis tools (jslint, jshint, resharper, etc) will flag

Comment: @apsillers is it really _valid_? (Is there a spec line stating that declaring the same variable more than once is acceptable, or is it just ignored in implementation?)

Comment: @Mathletics Yes, see [EMCAScript 10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5), step 8: for each VariableDeclaration with some identier `dn`, the interpreter checks if a variable with identifier `dn` is already declared in-scope, and only acts if it does not yet exist.

Comment: @apsillers perfect, that's what I wanted to see. Thanks!

Comment: @jbabey Thanks, that's a good example of something "going wrong" with the first.

Answer (score 4):

IMO the second should be preferred.

It's more communicative, and closer to what's actually happening (e.g., [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)).

I'm also not a fan of hiding variable declarations inside what *look* like scopes but aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code is wrong; you've declared the same variable multiple times.

JSHint will complain about it.

Comment: The parser won't, though.