# JavaScript for loop index strangeness

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick

I'm relatively new to JS so this may be a common problem, but I noticed something strange when dealing with for loops and the onclick function. I was able to replicate the problem with this code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            alert(i);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="">hi</a>
<br />
<a href="">bye</a>

</body>

</html>
```

When clicking the links I would expect to get '0' and '1', but instead I get '2' for both of them. Why is this?

BTW, I managed to solve my particular problem by using the 'this' keyword, but I'm still curious as to what is behind this behavior.

Comment: Please show an example of how you solved the problem with "this."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are having [a very common closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) in the `for` loop.

Variables enclosed in a closure share the same single environment, so by the time the `onclick` callback is executed, the loop has run its course and the `i` variable will be left pointing to the last entry.

You can solve this with even more closures, using a function factory:

```
function makeOnClickCallback(i) {  
   return function() {  
      alert(i);
      return false;
   };  
} 

var i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = makeOnClickCallback(i);
}
```

This can be quite a tricky topic, if you are not familiar with how closures work. You may to check out the following Mozilla article for a brief introduction:

- [Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

---

Note: I would also suggest not to use `var` inside the `for` loop, because this may trick you in believing that the `i` variable has block scope, when on the other hand the `i` variable is just like the `buttons` variable, scoped within the function.

Answer (score 9):

You need to store the state of the `i` variable, because by the time the event fires, the scoped state of `i` has increased to the maximum loop count.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            buttons[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(i);
                return false;
            }
        })(i);
    }
}
```

The above example creates an anonymous function with a single argument `i`, which is then called with `i` being passed as that argument.  This creates a new variable in a separate scope, saving the value as it was at the time of that particular iteration.

Comment: Creating functions in a loop is not recommended

Comment: @Ryan: I'm not sure if that's pedantry or confusion talking.  You're repeating a JSLint/JSHint warning without taking the time to understand what it means.  Take a look at the [docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#loopfunc) for an example of a function that shouldn't be created in a loop.  IIFEs are acceptable because it's pretty much the only option in some scenarios until `let` becomes universally supported.  The accepted answer creates functions in loops too, no down vote or comment there, though?

Comment: Okay, let me clarify: You're creating *two* functions in a loop. The IIFE, and the click handler. The accepted answer is creating one function in a loop: the click handler. Thus, the accepted answer minimizes the inefficiencies, while yours maximizes them.

Comment: @Ryan: so you *were* being pedantic then, because you down voted over a micro optimisation.  And not even a real one, at that, because it fails to consider the compiler's own optimisations.  In Chrome's console, the IIFE comes out at ~100ms faster over 1 million operations (I encourage you to check it).  Not that it even matters, because the question is looping from `i` = `0` to `2`, so the difference will be immeasurable.  Congratulations, you're the traffic officer who gives the guy a parking fine for arriving back at his car 1 second after his ticket expires.

Comment: *:sigh:* Yes, I guess I was being pedantic. So sue me. Go take your perfs and your compilers and your "I'm right and I have 126k rep" and prance around your perfect little world with all rightness and perfiness of everything you ever wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a order of execution issue

[How to assign event callbacks iterating an array in javascript (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104321/how-to-assign-event-callbacks-iterating-an-array-in-javascript-jquery/1104440#1104440)

Basically, the click handler accesses `i` well after the loop has exited, and therefore `i` is equal to `2`.

Comment: It is also a scope issue, `i` is hanging around when it is not apparent it should.

Comment: Right, which is why I linked to a post of mine about closures.