# What's the efficient way to get the first updated value in my case?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following js code snippet:

```
var myloop=function(element){
  ...
  var myValue;
 
  element.onClick(){
      //GET the first value of variable "myValue"
  };
};
myloop.start();
```

When `myloop` started, the body of `myloop` function will be executed **serverl times** and the **local variable** `myValue` will be updated each time `myloop` has been run.

Inside `myloop` function, I have an **event handler** `element.onClick()`, this event handler is only interested in the **first updated value** of local variable `myValue`.

I would like to ask some proposal of the **most efficient way** to get the **first updated value of `myValue`** inside the handler.

My implementation is to define a `index` and a `Array` outside `myloop` function , and store all the updated values inside the array, then in the handler, I get the first element from the array which is the first updated value of `myValue`. But I don't this this is efficient, since the rest updated value in the array is useless.

So, anybody can give some other proposal to get the first updated value of `myValue` inside the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myValue` is defined in the scope of `myLoop`, and when you're inside element's `onclick`, you'll be referencing the space in memory of that variable, not a copy.

So, you need to create a new scope to retain that reference. This will not create a copy, but as this scope will not be updated with the new value, it'll be still referencing the old one.

Based on @andy-e answer to [JavaScript for loop index strangeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803351/javascript-for-loop-index-strangeness/2803383#2803383):

```
var myloop=function(element){
    ...
    var myValue;

    (function (myValue) {
        element.onclick = function () {
            //GET the first value of variable "myValue"
        }
    })(myValue);
}
```

This is, IMHO the "correct" way to solve that. Maybe a more efficient way to do this is declare a global variable named something like `firstValue`, and when you set `myValue` (you can make a setter if you change it is a public property), check if firstValue is `null`. In that case you replace the value, either way, don't do anything.

Good luck!