# Javascript Function not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a javascript code smaller using a for loop, im new to javascript but I thought this would work,

Im trying to make this smaller:

```
   $("li#li_item1").click(function(){
    all();
    $("div#item1").fadeIn("fast");
})

$("li#li_item2").click(function(){
    all();
    $("div#item2").fadeIn("fast");
})

$("li#li_item3").click(function(){
    all();
    $("div#item3").fadeIn("fast");
})

$("li#li_item4").click(function(){
    all();
    $("div#item4").fadeIn("fast");
})
```

Using this:

```
    var AantalItem = 159;

    for(var k=0;k<=AantalItems;k++) {
    $("li#li_item" + k).click(function(){
        all();
        $("div#item" + k).fadeIn("fast");
    })

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=k;
}
```

When using the smaller code the fade in just wont work

This is the all():

```
    var all = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=AantalItems;i++) {
        $("div#item" + i).fadeOut("fast");
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript for loop index strangeness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803351/javascript-for-loop-index-strangeness)

Comment: Yeah, 'k' is always === AantalItems-1 when the click handler is executed. But, apart from that, the original code is totally easier to read.

Comment: Missing a ";" as well to close the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to closures effect.

try this:

```
for(var k=0;k<=AantalItems;k++) {
  $("li#li_item" + k).click(createClickFunction(k));
}

function createClickFunction(k) {
     return function() {
            all();
            $("div#item" + k).fadeIn("fast");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! but it didn't seem to do it, it also wont fade out anymore using that hmm

Comment: This seems to do it, but it now fades out and then fades back in so it double fades out

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function returning a function and pass `k` to it:

```
for(var k=0;k<=AantalItems;k++) {
    $("li#li_item" + k).click((function(k){
        return function() {
            all();
            $("div#item" + k).fadeIn("fast");
        }
    })(k));
```

or just add a common class to those items, and linked object's id to its `data` property - then the whole code will look like:

```
$('.commonClass').click(function() {
    $('.anotherCommonClassForDivs').fadeOut("fast");
    $('div#' + $(this).data('id')).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

and html:

```
<li class="commonClass" data-id="item1">whatever</li>
<li class="commonClass" data-id="item2">whatever</li>

<div class="anotherCommonClassForDivs" id="item1">data for item1</div>
<div class="anotherCommonClassForDivs" id="item2">data for item2</div>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zn5C/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  function fadeinAll() {
         $('li#li_item').find('div').each(function () { $(this).fadeIn("fast"); })
     }
     function fadeoutAll() {
         $('li#li_item').find('div').each(function () { $(this).fadeOut("fast"); })
     }
```