# Cannot set property 'comment' of undefined inside .then()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Why is `obj[i]` undefined inside `.then()`?

```
obj = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': '22', 'group': 'grA'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'mike', 'age': '24', 'group': 'grA'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'anne', 'age': '25', 'group': 'grB'}]

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj[i]) // has the right value
    this.commentService.getAllComments(obj[i].id).then((res) => {
        ...
        console.log(obj[i]) // undefined ???
    })
}
```

Is there any posibility I can solve this situation and is it there an explanation why is undefined? Thank you for your time!

EDIT: The problem was that I was using `var` instead of `let`. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue or at least your full code.

Comment: infamous for loop.... wait it is using let....

Comment: Sorry, typo. I edited.

Comment: normally this issue is when you use var and not let in the for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript for loop index strangeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803351/javascript-for-loop-index-strangeness)

Comment: I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `var` will define variable on the wrapping function level. Since your code inside promise then callback is running after the for loop finished execution, you'll always get the `i === obj.length`. To avoid this, you can define block scope local variable, using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword.

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { // let instead of var
    console.log(obj[i]) // has the right value
    this.commentService.getAllComments(obj[i].id).then((res) => {
        ...
        console.log(obj[i]) // has the right value
    })
}
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?